# Is it possible to keep `if ... in` and `{` on the same line without breaking the code?

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements, operators, autohotkey, brackets

```
;  not work
Var := "Var"

if Var in Foo,Bar,Baz {
  MsgBox statement 1
  MsgBox statement 2
} else {
  MsgBox statement 3
  MsgBox statement 4
}

;  not work
Var := "Var"

if (Var in Foo,Bar,Baz) {
  MsgBox statement 1
  MsgBox statement 2
} else {
  MsgBox statement 3
  MsgBox statement 4
}

;  works, but the brace positions are inconsistent,
;    is it possible to keep `if ... in` and `{`
;    on the same line without breaking the code?
Var := "Var"

if Var in Foo,Bar,Baz
{
  MsgBox statement 1
  MsgBox statement 2
} else {
  MsgBox statement 3
  MsgBox statement 4
}
```

Comment: You could place the braces (and the else) *consistently* on their own line (which is the alternative style to the "Egyptian brackets" you are looking for in your question).

Comment: @DevSolar Yes, but I'm wondering is there a way to preserve the "Egyptian brackets" without breaking the code.

Comment: I got that, which is why I wrote a comment instead of an answer. Personally, I *abhor* Egyptian brackets, because they lose visual information (start / end of a block), and make the code denser, which IMO does not equate to readability. Just my €0.02.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if ... in`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/IfIn.htm)</sup> is legacy and therefore you can't wrap it inside parentheses, since that would denote an expression. And not being able to place the bracket on the same line is just a limitation with `if ... in`.

There, unfortunately, isn't a direct modern replacement, so what you're asking is not possible with `if ... in`.

However, you can just ditch `if ... in` and legacy syntax and use e.g. the regex match shorthand operator `~=`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#regex)</sup> like so:

```
Var := "Var"

if (Var ~= "Foo|Bar|Baz") {
  MsgBox, % "nope"
} else if (Var ~= "Foo|Var|Baz") {
  MsgBox, % "yup"
}
```

---

Edit based on [user3419297](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3419297)'s comment:

If you don't [anchor](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) the regex pattern, it will match substrings as well. If you know there to be a risk of matching substrings, be sure to add in the `^` and `$` anchors e.g. like this:

```
(Var ~= "^(Foo|Var|Baz)$")
```

Comment: @Wenfang Du why do you have to edit every single answer. Legitimately quite annoying. Sure it's fine to edit if there's grammatical stuff to fix and what not, but a previous answer of mine you edited in false information, which I had to revert, and now you're removing my personal style of linking the docs for whatever reason.

Comment: @0x464e: `} else if (Var ~= "Foo|ar|Baz") {` results in "yup" with  `~=`.  Isn't better to use `} else if (Var = "Foo" || Var = "Var" || Var = "Baz") {` in this case?

Comment: That is a good point, would be good to use the regex anchors `^` and `$` in most cases. I'll edit my answer to mention this.

Comment: @0x464e: You can also correct "There, unfortunately, isn't a direct modern replacement" because there is as you see in my example, only less elaborated.

Comment: That's just a normal if statement, just like you could do in legacy. It's not a replacement for `if ... in`.

Comment: Isn't it? I wonder. Does it not work in v2?

Comment: There is also [InStr()](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/InStr.htm) for searching within a string's content : `} else if (InStr(Var, "Foo")  || InStr(Var, "Var") || InStr(Var, "Baz")) {`

Comment: I think we're not understanding each other. What I meant is that I don't think a normal if-statement with a bunch of OR-conditions is a direct modern replace for the legacy `if ... in`. A direct modern replacement doesn't exist (yet), not even in v2. Although, `in` is a reserved keyword in v2, so maybe something is coming. What I would consider a modern replacement (in v1) for `if ... in`, would be e.g. the existence of a function such as `IfIn(var, list)`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
Var := "Foo"
MsgBox % var = "Foo" ? "Statement 1"    ; if var  = foo
       : var = "Bar" ? "Statement 2"    ; if var  = bar
       : var = "Baz" ? "Statement 3"    ; if var  = baz
       :               "Statement 4"    ; if var != foo,bar and baz
```

OR just(same thing as above, but 2 lines):

```
Var := "Foo"
MsgBox % var = "Foo" ? "Statement 1" : var = "Bar" ? "Statement 2" : var = "Baz" ? "Statement 3" : "Statement 4"
```

[Documentation for ternary operator in autohotkey is here.](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#ternary)